# popup align to right instead of left

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a popup:

```
<Popup IsOpen="{Binding Path=AddMenuIsOpen, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
               StaysOpen="False"
               Placement="Bottom"
               PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=AddButton}">
```

In the preview it aligns nicely to the left of the "AddButton":

[image]

but when running it aligns to the right:

[image]

Any idea what might have caused it and how to fix it?

**Update** Apparently the problem is much more in depth than this. Even Popups that are part of the Menu control are aligning wrong:

[image]

Menus and popups in WPF apps (like Microsoft's) works fine on my computer. I thought it must be  a bug or some problem with the app configuration.
Any idea of what can I do to fix it?

**Update II** if I assign the `Placement` property to `"Right"` it actually aligns to the left, but if I assign it `"Left"` it's assigned to the right.

Comment: Can you provide MCVE?

Comment: @FoggyFinder what do you mean?

Comment: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @FoggyFinder - I can't because I don't know what causes the problem. Look at the updates... it's not a problem with my code. If you gave me an idea for what could cause the problem (my machine, my os, the version of Visual Studio I'm using, the compiler...?) I could check or give more details.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980616/wrong-alignment-of-contextmenu-and-popup-wpf-controls-on-windows-10